# Extracting embedded images from a plain text email in PHP

Tags: php, email

I have an email as a plain text file with embedded images, header etc. I want to extract these images from the file.

imap_fetchstructure() seems to be well working function for that.
It is used in this class, however all the imap_* functions require an IMAP connection:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-email-extract-inline-image-attachments

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just found this class:
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3169-PHP-Decode-MIME-e-mail-messages.html

This is capable of extracting embedded images. Easy and powerful.